# Given two arbitrary Orderings R and S on an arbitrary set X, decide whether a) $R∩S$ b) $R\cup S$ c) $R\circ S$ necessarily be an ordering.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

Given two arbitrary Orderings $R$ and $S$ on an arbitrary set $X$, decide which of the following will necessarily be an ordering. a) $R\cap S$ b) $R \cup S$ c) $R\circ S$ (concatenation of R and S).

For a) I've argued that $R \cap S$ is only applicable to subset of $X$, hence it is also an ordering.

b) I've said that we are just taking a union of two ordering without changing any properties of the ordering, so it must also be an ordering.

c) I am not so sure about c. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose with orderings you mean partial orderings, that is, binary relations which are reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.
So let $R$ and $S$ be two such relations on a set $X$.

(a) It's clear that that $R \cap S$ is reflexive; if $(a,b), (b,a) \in R \cap S$, then they belongs to both pairs, whence $b=a$ using the anti-symmetry in one of the relations (anyone); for transitivity $(a,b), (b,c) \in R \cap S$, then these pairs belong to each of the relations, which are transitive, whence $(a,c)$ belongs to each of them too and therefore to $R \cap S$.

(b) $R \cup S$ doesn't have to be a partial ordering.
For example, say $X = \{0,1\}$, $R = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ and $S = \{(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)\}$.
Then $(0,1), (1,0) \in R \cup S$; by anti-symmetry it should be $0=1$, which is not the case.

(c) $R \circ S$ doesn't have the be partial ordering either.
Take the same example as in (b).
From $(0,1) \in R$ and $(1,1) \in S$, it follows that $(0,1) \in R \circ S$;
from $(1,1) \in R$ and $(1,0) \in S$, it follows that $(1,0) \in R \circ S$;
again from this it should follow that $0=1$, if this was a partial ordering.
Hence it is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a good answer. Though, I have to admit that b) was a surprise :D.

Comment: Generally, the union of transitive relations doesn't have to be transitive, although this one is. It would be another way of failing to be a partial ordering. This example has the advantage that it works as a counterexample for the composition case. Good luck in your studies.